# Admin Backend Layout problem after extension install

Tags: magento2, admin, css, backend

So I have installed an extension (sagepay suite by ebizmarts) on Magento 2.17 but instead of doing the install via composer I did it the manual way by unzipping the extension into the Code folder.

After this, I did the usual of:

- Execute Magento setup upgrade - `$ bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- Clean cache and generated code - `$ bin/magento cache:clean and then $ rm -rf var/generation/*`
- Run magento compiler to generate auto-generated classes - `$ bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Static Content Deploy

Now both the backend and the website looks strange, as if the static files or CSS styling is not being applied. I thought there was a problem with the extension, so I deleted the extension and reran the steps above, but the problem is still there, so I am guessing I have missed an important step - Any ideas?

I have noticed some errors in the recompile command, these are to do with the Blank / luma theme which is installed such as:

frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email-inline.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. Run it and the CSSs should be back. It's unrelated to the newly installed module.